# Python library to iterate over multidimensional arrays with rules

Tags: python, iterator

Is there a way in python to iterate over multiple dimensions with conditions efficiently? Consider the following use case:

```
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i+1, N):
        for k in range(N):
            if (k != i) and (k != j):
                 print(i,j,k)
```

For e.g. `N = 4` this would yield

```
0 1 2
0 1 3
0 2 1
0 2 3
0 3 1
0 3 2
1 2 0
1 2 3
1 3 0
1 3 2
2 3 0
2 3 1
```

Is there an iterator in python that can produce this and similar output using rules? I imagine something like this

```
for i,j,k in fancy_iter(N=4, ndim=3, rules={'j > i', 'k != i', 'k != j'}):
    print(i,j,k)
```

**Edit**: It is expected that the iterator does not waste cycles excessively. Looping over all combinations of parameters and then excluding those that do not match the condition may get very slow in higher dimensions.

Comment: is there a specific scenario for which you want to do this, or are you just looking for a generalized solution?

Comment: A generalized solution. A library that implements a version of `fancy_iter` with flexible number of dimensions and a few basic rules to choose from

Comment: You can write a wrapper around a `itertools.product()` call so that it skips certain combinations if they don't follow your rules. I doubt there's a premade solution for this

Comment: `itertools.product()` is a solution, except it is very wasteful in terms of performance in higher dimensions if I have a lot of constraints. I'm sure there are multiple libraries designed for parameter exploration, for example I've heard of `pypet`, but I am not familiar with it